# MySQL left join excludes non-matching records?

Tags: mysql, left-join

When I execute this MySQL query, I get correct results as expected:

```
select h.ID AS ProductID, h.ProductTitle, u.Username, ht.ProductType, hd.Difficulty-- , ifnull(sum(pv.UpVote),0) - ifnull(sum(pv.DownVote),0) AS NetVotes
from Products h 
join Users u on h.UserID = u.ID 
join ProductTypes ht on h.ProductTypeID = ht.ID 
join ProductDifficulties hd 
on h.ProductDifficultyID = hd.ID 
-- left join ProductVotes pv
-- on h.ID = pv.ProductID
```

Notice I commented out the last column in the select (aggregate) and the left join. But when I include everything in the sql, ONLY records that have a matching ProductVotes record get included:

```
select h.ID AS ProductID, h.ProductTitle, u.Username, ht.ProductType, hd.Difficulty, ifnull(sum(pv.UpVote),0) - ifnull(sum(pv.DownVote),0) AS NetVotes
from Products h 
join Users u on h.UserID = u.ID 
join ProductTypes ht on h.ProductTypeID = ht.ID 
join ProductDifficulties hd 
on h.ProductDifficultyID = hd.ID 
left join ProductVotes pv
on h.ID = pv.ProductID
```

I would expect this behavior from an inner join, but not a left join. Why is the left join excluding records without a matching ProductVotes record? And how can I have those included, just like in the first query above?

EDIT: Originally I had a `LIMIT 0, 10` at the end of my query, and some folks thought this was causing the problem. I removed the limit clause and the problem still remains, so that had nothing to do with it. Now I have removed the `LIMIT` clause from my original post because it's irrelevant. Still awaiting an answer. :-)

Here are the full results of `select * from ProductVotes`:

```
ID ProductID UserID UpVote DownVote
 2         1      2      1 NULL
 3         1      3      1 NULL
 4         1      4      1 NULL
 5         1      5      1 NULL
 6         1      6      1 NULL
 7         1      7      1 NULL
 8         1      8      1 NULL
 9         1      9   NULL    1
10         1     10   NULL    1
22         1      1      1 NULL
```

(Notice only 10 records in the table.)

**IMPORTANT: Please notice the aggregations in my select statements: `ifnull(sum(pv.UpVote),0) - ifnull(sum(pv.DownVote),0) AS NetVotes`**

Comment: May be remove limit? You will see all rows matching and unmatching.

Comment: No way of that. Did you shortened statements?  The second statement can not return less rows then 1 statement

Comment: No metter how many there are rows in votes table. Even if it is empty, second statement can not produce less rows then first statement. Are you sure you are not filtering result somewhere?

Comment: The 2nd query returns exactly 1 row, and it's the row that has a ProductID of 1. It's behaving just like an inner join. I have never seen this happen before, been using MySQL for 12 years. I am baffled.

Comment: Inner join would return 10 rows :) because there 10 products with id 1 in votes table.

Comment: That would be true if there was no SUM. Notice: `ifnull(sum(pv.UpVote),0) - ifnull(sum(pv.DownVote),0) AS NetVotes`. It's an aggregation in the select.

Comment: You have sum, where is group by?

Comment: MySQL doesn't require a Group By -- it just sees the aggregate column and infers group by. I have done this many times and always got correct results. Whereas in MS SQL Server an explicit group by is required. I think nobody noticed the SUMs in my select statements. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76549/discussion-between-sweatcoder-and-giorgi-nakeuri).

Comment: Of course you will get only 1 row. If mysql is doing grouping. May be subquery will give you desired result

Comment: see my answer, may be this is what you want, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select h.ID AS ProductID, h.ProductTitle, u.Username, ht.ProductType, hd.Difficulty, 
(select ifnull(sum(pv.UpVote),0) - ifnull(sum(pv.DownVote),0) from ProductVotes pv where h.ID = pv.ProductID ) AS NetVotes
from Products h 
join Users u on h.UserID = u.ID 
join ProductTypes ht on h.ProductTypeID = ht.ID 
join ProductDifficulties hd 
on h.ProductDifficultyID = hd.ID
```

Comment: The LIMIT is necessary for my grid paging to work. And I don't see how this can be the problem. My query #1 brings back 6 records, which is correct. My query #2 only brings back 1 record, because the non-matching rows are being filtered. Neither query hits the 10-record limit.

Comment: It is impossible. You are not showing us something important

Comment: Thank you for persisting, Giorgi! That works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, but imho that is bad request. it will slowdown very fast once you'll have more data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not `LEFT JOIN` it is `LIMIT 0,10`.

So to fix it you can remove `LIMIT` from the query.

Or you can try to change the order the way `LEFT JOIN`ed records being placed at the bottom like:

```
SELECT 
  h.ID AS ProductID, 
  h.ProductTitle, 
  u.Username, 
  ht.ProductType, 
  hd.Difficulty, 
  hv.NetVotes
FROM Products h 
LEFT JOIN Users u 
ON h.UserID = u.ID 
LEFT JOIN ProductTypes ht 
ON h.ProductTypeID = ht.ID 
LEFT JOIN ProductDifficulties hd 
ON h.ProductDifficultyID = hd.ID 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
      ProductID,
      SUM(IFNULL(UpVote,0) - IFNULL(hv.DownVote,0)) AS NetVotes
   FROM
      ProductVotes
   GROUP BY ProductID
) hv
ON h.ID = hv.ProductID
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: The LIMIT is necessary for my grid paging to work. And I don't see how this can be the problem. My query #1 brings back 6 records, which is correct. My query #2 only brings back 1 record, because the non-matching rows are being filtered. Neither query hits the 10-record limit.

Comment: Also, this didn't change anything: `ORDER BY IF(hv.ProductID IS NULL,0,1) ASC`

Comment: Post sample of your data please to continue duscussion

Comment: do you know about sqlfiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? we need all your tables data samples

Comment: @SweatCoder check updated query. But I still need data samples.